# Is there an interface applied to serializable types in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

I want to create a class that looks roughly like this:

```
class MyWrapperClass<T: IsSerializable>(val someData: T) {
  fun stringifyMe(): String {
    return Json.encodeToString(someData)
  }
  

}
```

My question is about that `IsSerializable` type. I'd like to accept only types that have been marked as `@Serializable`, so that I can then call `Json.encodeToString()` on them. Is this possible?

I tried the code as noted, but I got the error "Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead.".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way that Kotlin Serialisation works is that the serialisation code for each serialisable thing is generated in the *companion object* of the class,  by processing the `@Serializable` annotation at compile time.

So something like

```
@Serializable
class Foo(val name: String)
```

becomes

```
@Serializable
class Foo(val name: String) {
    companion object {
        fun serializer(): KSerializer<Foo> {
            // implementation details...
            // returns a serializer for Foos in some way 
        }
    }
}
```

Interfaces can't require a type to have a companion object. Interfaces can only require things related to *instances* of a type, after all. So there is no interface for this.

As is said in [this Kotlin forums comment](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/serialization/20209/7), one way you could guarantee a successful serialisation is to require the caller to pass in the generated `serializer()`:

```
class MyWrapperClass<T>(
    val someData: T, 
    val strategy: SerializationStrategy<T>
) {
    fun stringifyMe(): String {
        return Json.encodeToString(strategy, someData)
    }
}
```

If the caller has a serialisable type, then they could do:

```
MyWrapperClass(someData, SomeSerializableType.serializer())
```

Even if a type is not marked with `@Serializable`, but the caller has got a `SerializationStrategy` for it using some other means, it is also possible to serialise the instance, and so is by definition, "serialisable".

---

I don't recommend this, but it is also possible to declare these two interfaces:

```
interface SerializationStrategyProvider<T> {
    fun serializer(): SerializationStrategy<T>
}

interface MySerializable<T: MySerializable<T>> {
    val serializationStrategyProvider: SerializationStrategyProvider<T>
}
```

Then your wrapper class can just have one parameter:

```
class MyWrapperClass<T: MySerializable>(val someData: T) {
    fun stringifyMe(): String {
        return Json.encodeToString(someData.serializationStrategyProvider.serializer(), someData)
    }
}
```

But the downside is of course that the callers need to implement this interface before they can use your class, and you cannot enforce *how* they implement this interface. The expected way is:

```
@Serializable
data class Foo(val bar: String): MySerializable<Foo> {
    companion object: SerializationStrategyProvider<Foo>
    override val serializationStrategyProvider
        get() = Foo
}
```